# What is the intended workflow with UIkit when creating a custom theme with Webpack?

Tags: sass, getuikit

We have Webpack for our project and we need to customize a great amount of things. I.E. we need to create our own theme. According to [the docs](https://getuikit.com/docs/sass#how-to-structure-your-theme), I should have:

```
@import 'theme/_import';

@import '~uikit/src/scss/variables';
@import '~uikit/src/scss/mixins';

@import "~uikit/src/scss/uikit";
```

Where the `theme` folder is a copy of `uikit/src/scss/theme`. However, I get an error:

> Undefined variable: "$global-muted-background".

So what should I do in this situation?

- Did I rightfully copy that `theme` folder? Is it meant for copy-paste and then modification? If yes, what do I import before that folder so that the necessary variables are declared?
- Should I copy the whole `variables-theme.scss` file and modify *it* instead? In that case, what's the purpose of splitting each component's variables into files, as the docs suggest? Also, everything would be a mess.
- Where should I put my custom global variables? In `theme/variables` and then import them in `theme/_import`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?